# Was any reform made at the World Bank to prevent a country for using its influence to pressure World Bank officials to alter its data?

Tags: corruption, world-bank

> China has tried over the past two decades to increase its influence
> over international institutions, including the IMF and the World
> Health Organization, and their policies.
>
> The changes made to the 2018 “Doing Business” report followed lobbying
> by Beijing for a better ranking and came ahead of a campaign by the
> World Bank to raise capital in which Beijing was expected to play a
> “key role,” the report said. China is the bank’s third-largest
> shareholder after the United States and Japan.

https://apnews.com/article/business-china-world-bank-jim-yong-kim-aee690d7ec87d9bbd4d36cc5fcfa7018

Was any reform made at the World Bank to prevent a country for using its influence to pressure World Bank officials to alter its data? Investigation found that World Bank leaders, including Kim, pressured bank staff to alter data to inflate the rankings of China, Azerbaijan, Saudi Arabia and the United Arab Emirates. I was wondering if any reform at the World Bank was made in order to prevent a similar thing to happen in the future.

Comment: "Kim, pressured bank staff to alter data to inflate the rankings of China, Azerbaijan, Saudi Arabia and the United Arab Emirates." Did the pressure produce any results? If not, why would reforms be needed?

Comment: I think 'alter the data' is very open to misinterpretation. There is an entire range of options between switching from one legitimate method to another that makes one appear better versus switching correct numbers to wrong more favorable ones. I don't know where on this scale China is and the World Bank certainly has some measures against straight out cheating but is also deslibaretely open to adjusting some methods.